# How to go about solving this particular limit?

Tags: limits

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\right)$

How to approach this problem?

My initial approach was to apply L'Hopitals Rule for the '0/0' indeterminate form but that kept going onn without yielding a solution.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah and I edited the question to make it more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply L’Hôpital’s rule.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ -\frac 1e \cdot (1+x)^{\frac 1x}\cdot \frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)} \\ =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+x)\log(1+x) -x}{x^2 +x^3} $$

Differentiating again, $$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1+x}{1+x} + \log(1+x) -1}{2x+3x^2} \\ =\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{2x+3x^2}  $$

Do it again.

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+6x)} = \frac 12$$

Comment: can you state under which indeterminate form did you apply L'Hopitals Rule ?

Comment: @KeshavanPurushothaman All of them are of the form $\frac 00$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you